# mongoose find if a nested subdocument (date type) is within a date interval

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Having trouble querying for a nested subdocument of type date and comparing it using the $gte command.

Here is my schema:

```
  a: {
    b: String,
    c: String,
    d: Date,
  },
```

Here is my mongoose find query:

```
SomeModel.find(
      { a: { $elemMatch: { d: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } } } } }, callback);
```

I get back nothing, when I definitely have at least one object matching this requirement in my database. I'm guessing my syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) -- `SomeModel.find({"a.d": {$gt: value} })`